# Unable to display a gif image in MIPSel device using Qt

Tags: qt4, mips, endianness

I am using Qt4.6.3 with Linux. I have compiled my application for a [MIPSel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPSel) device. I need to display a GIF image in my application. If I compile my application and run it on the desktop, the gif image is displayed. It is not displayed in when the application runs on the MIPSel device.

I have used QMovie and QLabel classes but no improvement. On the device, PNG format can be displayed.

By calling  `supportedFormats()` function, I got the information that only PNG and BMP are supported by the device. How can i get gif format support in my device? Please, can anybody give me good suggestions?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the required image processing plugins not being included on your device. Start with this [documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/plugins-howto.html#locating-plugins) and [this page too](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/deployment-x11.html#qt-plugins).